# Android Histogram equalization algorithm gives me really bright or red image

Tags: android, image, algorithm

I am doing histogram equalization on an image. I first get the RGB image and convert it to YUV. I run the histogram equalization algorithm on Y' of YUV and then convert back to RGB. Is it me, or does the image look weird? I am doing this correctly? this image is pretty bright, other images are a little red.

Here are the before/after images:

[image: before]
[image: after]

The algorithm (the commented values are values that I used previously for conversion. Both yield pretty much the same results) :

```
    public static void createContrast(Bitmap src) {

    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    Bitmap processedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());

    int A = 0,R,G,B;
    int pixel;
    float[][] Y = new float[width][height];
    float[][] U = new float[width][height];
    float[][] V = new float [width][height];
    int [] histogram = new int[256];
    Arrays.fill(histogram, 0);

    int [] cdf = new int[256];
    Arrays.fill(cdf, 0);
    float min = 257;
    float max = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            //Log.i("TEST","("+x+","+y+")");
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);

            /*Log.i("TESTEST","R: "+R);
            Log.i("TESTEST","G: "+G);
            Log.i("TESTEST","B: "+B);*/

            // convert to YUV
            /*Y[x][y] = 0.299f * R + 0.587f * G + 0.114f * B;
            U[x][y] = 0.492f * (B-Y[x][y]);
            V[x][y] = 0.877f * (R-Y[x][y]);*/

            Y[x][y] = 0.299f * R + 0.587f * G + 0.114f * B;
            U[x][y] = 0.565f * (B-Y[x][y]);
            V[x][y] = 0.713f * (R-Y[x][y]);
            // create a histogram
            histogram[(int) Y[x][y]]+=1;
            // get min and max values
            if (Y[x][y] < min){
                min = Y[x][y];
            }
            if (Y[x][y] > max){
                max = Y[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    cdf[0] = histogram[0];
    for (int i=1;i<=255;i++){
        cdf[i] = cdf[i-1] + histogram[i];
        //Log.i("TESTEST","cdf of: "+i+" = "+cdf[i]);
    }

    float minCDF = cdf[(int)min];
    float denominator = width*height - minCDF;
    //Log.i("TEST","Histeq Histeq Histeq Histeq Histeq Histeq");
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            //Log.i("TEST","("+x+","+y+")");
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            Y[x][y] = ((cdf[ (int) Y[x][y]] - minCDF)/(denominator)) * 255;
            /*R = minMaxCalc(Y[x][y] + 1.140f * V[x][y]);
            G = minMaxCalc (Y[x][y] - 0.395f * U[x][y] - 0.581f * V[x][y]);
            B = minMaxCalc (Y[x][y] + 2.032f * U[x][y]);*/

            R = minMaxCalc(Y[x][y] + 1.140f * V[x][y]);
            G = minMaxCalc (Y[x][y] - 0.344f * U[x][y] - 0.714f * V[x][y]);
            B = minMaxCalc (Y[x][y] + 1.77f * U[x][y]);
            //Log.i("TESTEST","A: "+A);
            /*Log.i("TESTEST","R: "+R);
            Log.i("TESTEST","G: "+G);
            Log.i("TESTEST","B: "+B);*/
            processedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
```

}

My next step is to graph the histograms before and after. I just want to get an opinion here.

Comment: I'd start by creating test images with several blocks of solid color to test this.

Comment: That image looks pretty good to me.  I expect your algorithm to brighten an image to the point where some part of it is pure white.  If you're getting some redness, that's bad.  Make sure your RGB->YUV->RGB path (without equalization) really is the identity function.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. First I will use a solid color to see the results and secondly on a solid color image I will make sure I am getting the same image back when running the convertion without histeq.

Comment: @JuanAcevedo hi did you figure it out? I am doing a similar project and was wondering if I can have a look at your updated code on this

Comment: Hi Riga, the above code is correct. For the minMaxCalc, I couldn't find it among my projects. I'll look a little more to see if I have it on another computer.

Comment: @JuanAcevedo Hi Juan, do you have an email because I have a few questions regarding your algorithm?

Comment: Look at my profile, it should be there. In all honesty though, I haven't touched image processing in over a year so I might be rusty.

Comment: @JuanAcevedo hi I cant find your email but had a question regarding the final two "for" loops. Where did you get the calculations for each RGB from? do you have a resource that you can link please?

Comment: @JuanAcevedo I don't suppose you have the minMaxCalc method available or when I can obtain it? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried looking for it, but I have not found it. Others have asked me. I didn't realize my code was not complete when I first posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little bit old, but let me answer.

The reason is the way histogram equalization works. The algorithm tries to use all of the 0-255 range instead of given image's range.

So if you give it a dark image, it will change relatively brighter pixels to white colors. And relatively darker colors to black colors.

If you give it a bright image, for the same reason it will get darkened.